Can bitwise operations do this?
I have a basic logic that I can implement with logical operators:
if a == true && b == false

I am wondering if I can do the same with bitwise operators?
XOR does this:
0 ^ 0 = false
0 ^ 1 = true
1 ^ 0 = true
1 ^ 1 = false

If I use XOR, this is what I'm looking for and it will work:
1 ^ 0 = true

However, XOR will also return this, which is NOT what I want:
0 ^ 1 = true

So, is there a way to do it with bitwise operators, without using any logical operators? I have a good understanding of bitwise operations and I can't see a solution for this, but that doesn't mean that I couldn't be missing something.

The natural bitwise operator to replace && would be &.

Bitwise, ((a << 1) | b) == 2

You can implement any logic with NAND gates. Your example can be implemented with 3 Nands (1 to negate b and 2 to implement the AND operator)

Do you just want to perform this operation on individual one-bit values, or bitwise across all bits of your inputs?

@NateEldredge Your 'a & ~b' seems to do the job. I'm still testing. It looks like it does the same job as 'a && !b', which is great.

What are the types of a and b? The test a == true suggests that the type of a is not bool, since a would do exactly the same thing as a == true.

In general, a == true && b == false is not the same as a && !b.  Specifically, if a is 2, a == true is false but a is true.  Beware!

@PeteBecker what I posted is not actual code, it's just something to convey the point... The types are boolean.

@aro -- questions about how to write code always involve the types of the things in question. If the type of a was int the answer would be different from the answer if it is bool.

@PeteBecker True/false should be a clue

@aro -- indeed, but a clue to what? int x = 3; if (x == true) ... is valid C and C++, and the true is a hint that whoever wrote the code is confused (maybe an old-time Windows programmer; Microsoft taught people lots of bad habits back in the day).

@PeteBecker yes, it is valid C and C++; it is also indicative of a severe disconnect from proper, straight thinking in the modern day.

@MikeNakis  It far from unusual for questions posted here to demonstrate "a severe disconnect from proper, straight thinking in the modern day".   It is also not unusual for questions to be posted, for someone to ask for clarification (as Pete did here in asking about the types of a and b) and for subsequent comments to reveal that the OP has such a disconnect.

@Peter my comment is not addressed to the OP; true, the OP could have written if a && !b and spare us from that if a == true && b == false, but my comment is addressed to user Pete Becker who noted that int x = 3; if (x == true) ... is valid C and C++, which of course it is, but it would not pass code review under my watch.

Keep in mind that how to do things with bit-wise operators very much depends on the types of the operands. Unlike boolean expressions where we don't need to care much.

@MikeNakis -- you have utterly missed the point. The issue isn't whether you like that particular code; it's simply that the question doesn't provide enough information to exclude it.

@PeteBecker I have not missed any point, thank you. In my comments, I choose what issue to talk about. You do not have a saying as to what issue I will address.

@MikeNakis -- um, your comment that you "addressed to [me]" had nothing to do with the point I was making. That's pretty much the definition of "missed the point".

It might be worth mentioning that simply exchanging && for & does not necessarily produce the same behavior as a consequence of short-circuit evaluation.

Here is a general table for all two-operand bitwise operations. The first column is the results desired for the operations 0•0, 0•1, 1•0, and 1•1, respectively. The second column is an expression on the first operand, a, and the second operand, b. The one you want is in the 0 0 1 0 row, a & ~b:



Desired Results
Bitwise Expression




0 0 0 0
0


0 0 0 1
a & b


0 0 1 0
a & ~b


0 0 1 1
a


0 1 0 0
~a & b


0 1 0 1
b


0 1 1 0
a ^ b


0 1 1 1
a | b


1 0 0 0
~(a | b)


1 0 0 1
~(a ^ b)


1 0 1 0
~b


1 0 1 1
a | ~b


1 1 0 0
~a


1 1 0 1
~a | b


1 1 1 0
~(a & b)


1 1 1 1
-1



(The last of those, -1, will create a pattern of all bits set when converted to any unsigned integer type.)

How about ~0 instead of -1? Seems more consistent with the rest.

@nocomment: ~0 will have the value −1 in C implementations using two’s complement, and that will function the same as -1. It will differ in one’s complement and sign-and-magnitude implementations. Those are archaic, and the forthcoming C standard may eliminate them. But as long as the standard allows for them, -1 is a more general solution that will work in any C implementation. While - is nominally not a bitwise operator, -1 is a constant expression. If OP specified a specific type T, we could use ~ (T) 0. Or we could use a | ~a.

And in those differing implementations, -1 gives the desired result and ~0 doesn't?

@nocomment: Using one’s complement, ~0 produces the value −0 or a trap representation. Using sign-and-magnitude, ~0 produces the largest-magnitude representable negative value.

If that's a problem, won't your other uses of ~ have the same problem?

There is something confusing in this answer, making it hard to understand. The • sign is sometimes used in math to denote multiplication, and in the context of booleans, multiplication is another name for the AND operation. However, that's not what you mean there. So, maybe a clarification is necessary regarding your notation.

@nocomment: No. The problem is not with ~. It is with the type of the constants, 0 or 1, differing from whatever type OP is using. ~ applied to a and b will operate on their (promoted) types. Even if they are wider than int, all their bits will be negated. With ~0, only the bits of an int would be negated, not all the bits of OP’s type, if it is wider.

unsigned int a = ~0; gives me 4294967295 while unsigned long int b = ~0; gives me 18446744073709551615 (link). So does the "only the bits of an int would be negated" only apply to one’s complement and sign-and-magnitude implementations?

According to the latest standard, C++ integers are always 2's complement. Unsigned integer arithmetic is always(not ÷0) well-defined with wrap-around for add/sub over/underflow. Most(not all) signed operations that result in sign bit change are UB.

The binary truth function you are looking for is either material nonimplication or converse nonimplication. The corresponding operators are not bitwise operators at all, but > and <, assuming the conventional mapping of true to 1 and false to 0.
if a > b

or
if b < a

It's worth noting a language could implement bitwise versions of > and <, but I'm not aware of any that do.

Just to note, I posted this answer before the c++ tag was added; the question was previously language-agnostic.

Assuming that we are assured that a and b always start with the value 0 or 1 (rather than just equal to 0 and not equal to 0), yes.
In logical terms, a == true && b == false is equivalent to a and not b. In C or C++ bitwise operations that would be a & (b ^ 1).

In general it is a bad idea to use bitwise operations for this.  If the values of a or b might have more than one bit set or have different non-zero bits set, you will not get the result you expect.  They are semantically different operations.
The expression a == true && b == false is also ill-advised rather than the safer and more succinct a && !b, which will work regardless of C or C++ and how (in C) true or false might be defined.
When written thus, of course the bitwise operation becomes rather obvious: a & ~d. However it remains dangerous - it will work if a and b are of type bool, but otherwise will depend on the specific values rather than Thier zero/non-zero Boolean state.

That expression (a == true && b == false) can be reduced to:
a == true      -->   a             --> a
b == false     -->  !b    (not b)  --> ~b

so if you apply the negation operator ~ to every bit of b and leave a as it is, you will get that the expression can be done for each bit of the word as:
(a & ~b)    [&& got converted into &]

Every logical expression can be converted in this way into a bitwise expression.  But beware that, in C, expressions can have side effects, if that is the case, the mapping from && to & is risky, as in the first case, the second subexpression is not evaluated if initially a == false.  In that case, the result will be 0 independently of what b bit is, and in that case, the second part is not executed (but you have only one bit of boolean information) and so, side effects would never happen, while in the second case (&), the right side of & is always executed.
